# While (true) loop with if...else statement is only outputting once for every two inputs

Tags: java, while-loop

For my assignment, I need to get user input, add that input to my ArrayList, print out the user's input, and then repeat until the user enters "done".

Why is my `if...else` statement taking input twice and only printing it out once, or rather why is it only storing and printing out every other line of user input?

My goal is to print out each line of user input, not every other line.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
int counter = 0;
ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    if (input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
        break;
    } else {
        destinations.add(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\tDestinations: " + destinations.get(counter));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling nextLine() twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user to enter a line twice and not once. Each call to method `nextLine()`, of class `java.util.Scanner`, will wait for input from the user.

Consider the following.

```java
int counter = 0;
ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    if ("done".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
        break;
    } else {
        destinations.add(line);
        System.out.println("\tDestinations: " + destinations.get(counter));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you no longer need `counter`: just print `line` instead of `destinations.get(counter)`.